# Use jQuery to combine values of two inputs in a third input

Tags: jquery, html, text, html-input

I'm just learning jQuery and I'm trying to take the two values from boxes one and two and add them together into another input separated by `||`.

For example if I add "hello" into the first text box and "you" in the second box I would like to display `hello||you` in the third box.

This is what I have so far: https://fiddle.jshell.net/a2n234eq/

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#1, #2").on("keyup", function(){
    $("#3").val($("#1").val() + "||" + $("#2").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want it like [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ovvgeds9/).

What I've done here is I've taken your code, and changed it so the value get's stored in a variable which is put into the third input when the last input has changed.

The code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
<input id="3">
```

**JS**

```
var value;
$('#1').change(function() {
    value = $(this).val();
});
$('#2').change(function() {
    value += "||"+$(this).val();
    $('#3').val(value);
});
```

**Don't forget to include jQuery in the HTML**

Hope this helps!